# Simulating ReactJS form tag with TestUtils doesn't trigger `onSubmit`

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using **Sinon** to spy on the method, but the method I'm spying doesn't seem to be called at all when I try to Simulate `onSubmit` on the `form` tag.

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vh2efzzb/).

Answer (score 1):

First of all, this line:

`React.addons.TestUtils.Simulate.submit(Instance, form.getDOMNode());`

Should be:

`React.addons.TestUtils.Simulate.submit(form.getDOMNode());`

But that doesn't solve the problem, because of the way your component is structured. You're already giving the current `_handleSubmit` function to React to call, and React will invoke that function. It won't call `Instance._handleSubmit()`, which is the one you've replaced. If you change your component to something like:

`var that = this;
...
<form onSubmit={function() { that._handleSubmit()}}>`

It works because you explicitly call the method on the instance.

But I would advice you to not assert that the method was called, but instead assert that whatever side effect it should perform was actually performed. Like mutating state, calling an external service, etc.

Comment: I see thanks. I'll give your comment a shot now. I'll comment back asap.